# React navigation - Alternative to navigation.reset with StackActions

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

Is there an alternative to `navigation.reset()` that uses StackActions?

I've tried a few things, for example:

```
navigation.popToTop()
navigation.replace('home')
```

Although this takes me where I want to go, it doesn't clear the entire navigation state.

If there are any other methods that don't use StackActions please let me know as well as I'm trying to learn if and how people handle this use case.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the use case you have?